# Custom Data Validation in Excel: 13 alphanumeric characters only, alpha characters must be uppercase

Tags: excel, validation

I'd like to use a validation rule for an input cell where the entry must be 13 alphanumeric characters long, and if alphas are used, they must be uppercase. I used the following, but it still allows entry of lowercase letters:

`=AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(K12,ROW(INDIRECT("1:13"&LEN(K12))),1),"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))),LEN(K12)=13)`

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `SEARCH` to `FIND` which is case sensitive.

Comment: Also you need to change this `"1:13"&LEN(K12)` to `"1:"&LEN(K12)` unless you like doing 1313 iterations.

Comment: This worked, Scott. Thank you, sir.